# Improve fit of a Gamma distribution

Tags: r, regression, gamma-distribution

My dependent variable has a distribution as below:

[image]

I fit a `gamma` distribution with `log` link using `glm` in R. It gives me the following fit:

[image]

My RMSE is around 18% and I am hoping there is a good room for improvement. I have tried fitting a `beta` distribution, with no major change. Looking for some direction to explore a better fit.

**Edit:**

Adding the `ggpairs` plot of my predictor and predicted variables:

[image]

Comment: Could you tell us about the explanatory variables you are using in your model?  The actual distribution of the response is almost totally irrelevant; only its distribution *conditional on the explanatory variables* matters.

Comment: I have used three categorical variables (each with two factor levels), and one continous variable also distributed between [0,1]. The continous predictor and predicted are very highly correlated. Is there any other information you would want?

Comment: Your histogram and scatterplot make the data look like they're truncated at 1. Is this true? I mean to say that when the outcome shows a value of 1, all we can say is that it is some outcome exceeding 1 like 1.3 or even 2.6 etc.

Comment: No, my predicted variable and independent variable are in [0,1]

Comment: The reason the outcome is exceeding 1 is because I have assumed a `gamma` distribution. I did try a `beta` regression, given the distribution is between [0,1], but `gamma` was philisophically a better fit as my predicted variable can be $[0,\inf]$. The data is though distributed in [0,1] without truncation.

Comment: @Divi In what sense is the Gamma dist'n a "better fit philosophically" if the variable you have collected is bound by 1? That strikes me as an immediate philosophical contradiction. That is to say, I'm assuming it's not merely an artifact of the data you have that they're bounded btn 0 and 1, but if you replicated the study 100 times, you would never have $x > 1$.

Comment: @AdamO It may be a "philosophical contradiction" (if that has any definite meaning), but it's not necessarily a practical problem. If we had to use models that adhered strictly to such data limits, the Normal distribution (among many) could almost never be applied, despite its usefulness.

Comment: My continuous variables are ratio, so they can never be more than one. However, because it is a practical problem, theoretically the ratio can be higher than one due to addition of overhead cost. So I can defend my use of a gamma distribution.

Comment: @Divi if you have two variables $X$ and $Y$ having a Gamma dist'n and their ratio interests you, it is a mathfact that $X/(X+Y)$ has a beta distribution. Is there any reason you might choose to model that instead?

Comment: @whuber my comment was slightly tongue in cheek since the OP claimed that the Gamma was philosophically a better fit.

Comment: @AdamO I think my comment wasn't clear. Both my X and Y variables are each ratio of other quantities, so each of them are between [0,1]. And I do have to model the ratio, and not the values, due to practical constraints.

Comment: Your question refers to a *single* "dependent value."  What is its connection with $X$ and $Y$, then?  And why aren't you modeling those "other quantities" directly rather than using only their ratios?  It's difficult to fathom what "practical constraints" would preclude such an approach, which is more statistically sound.

Comment: My $Y$ is the dependent variable in the `ggpairs` plot. $X$ is the continuous independent variable and $A, B, C$ are the categorical independent variables. My research community models this problem with $Y$ as dependent and $X$ as independent, and both them are ratios so they theoretically follow a beta distribution. However, the fit is never great with a beta, and I was hoping for some other direction I could explore.